# Java Nodes LinkedList

Tags: java, nodes

Java Nodes/ LinkedList(Pointer based)
the program is basically a node that includes student attributes:

first name
last name
age
ID 
Major

There are 3 classes : 
1- nodeclass
2- class for the methods (add in the beginning, and add in the end, search etc..
3 -the test class

the problem that I'm facing is that I am confused on how to include all the students attributes into one node.

Now an example of the node class(1) to add an integer is:

```
public class IntNodeF14
{
  int item; 
  IntNodeF14 next;
}
```

how can I create a node that will accept all the students attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your class generic :

```
public class NodeF14<T>
{
  NodeF14<T> next;
  T data;
}
```

`data` would hold the data of a single node.

Then you can create a `NodeF14` for any type of data you need.

For example :

```
Student student = new Student (firstName,lastName);
NodeF14<Student> studentNode = new NodeF14<Student> (student);
```

If you can't use generics, you'll have to include all the properties (or a Student member holding all the properties) in the Node class, but in this case your list will only support one type of data.

Comment: The Student student = new Student(firstName,lastName); is in the test class , but what do I put in the class where I will be applying the functions ( add in the end and add in the beginning etc..)?

Comment: Let's say in the functions class the add in beginning function is something like this:
<code>
        public void Addb(int x)
          {
           IntNodeF14 NewN= new IntNodeF14();
           NewN.item=x;
           NewN.next=First;
           if(Empty())
               {
            First=NewN;
            Last=First;
           }
          else  First=NewN;
    
           count++;
         }
</code>

(but this is for an integer) 

in the case of the students multiple attributes, what should i do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Add(int x)` adds an int to the list, so that makes it a linked list of ints. You'll need a generic class, lets call it LinkedList<T>, which contains elements of type T. The add method will accept a generic parameter T. Then if you create a list of Students : LinkedList<Student> list = new LinkedList<Student>(), you can add a student with list.add(student).

Comment: Student student = new Student (firstName,lastName); (Included in the test class)


NodeF14<Student> studentNode = new NodeF14<Student> (student); (functions class)

right?

Comment: And let's say

public void Addb(String firstname, String lastname, int ID)
   


 {
     NodeF14 NewN= new NodeF14();
    NewN.data=firstname;
           NewN.next=First;


how can I apply this to the last name and ID as well

Comment: @AJ1 Addb(String firstname, String lastname, int ID) doesn't make sense to me. It's better to group these properties in a Student object and then have Addb(Student student) (or better yet Addb(T data), if you use generics).